# typescript linter for CodeMirror

Tags: typescript, codemirror

I use CodeMirror editor in one of my one CMS apps.  Does anyone have any suggestions/experience of incorporating a typescript linter into CodeMirror?

P.S. I am aware of ts lint https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint but it is not obvious how to incorporate this.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem all you need to do is install `tsd`:

```
$ npm install -g tsd
```

Install the CodeMirror type definitions in your project:

```
# from your project folder
$ tsd install codemirror --save
```

That will create a folder named `typings` that will contain a filed [`codemirror.d.ts`](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/codemirror/codemirror.d.ts).

You can then add a reference to this file in the TypeScript files that invoke the CodeMirror API:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/codemirror/codemirror.d.ts" />

// USE CODE MIRROR HERE
```

Once you have finished coding you can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [gulp-tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tslint).

```
# npm install gulp gulp-tslint vinyl-source-stream vinyl-buffer --save-dev
```

Create a `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp        = require("gulp"),
    source      = require("vinyl-source-stream"),
    buffer      = require("vinyl-buffer"),
    tslint      = require("gulp-tslint");


gulp.task("lint", function() {
  return gulp.src([
                __dirname + "/source/**/**.ts", // Path to your TS files
              ])
             .pipe(tslint())
             .pipe(tslint.report("verbose"));
});
```

An finally run the Gulp task:

```
$ gulp lint
```

If you need additional help with Gulp check out the [Official Getting Started](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `lint` addon : http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_lint to provide lint errors from `tslint -> code mirror`

## More

You can even wrap up the lint addon into something nicer like a promise based linter (warning complex code but just a demo of something that does work ) https://github.com/basarat/tsb/blob/master/src/app/codemirror/codeEditor.tsx / https://github.com/basarat/tsb/blob/master/src/app/codemirror/addons/linter.ts

Comment: I got the wrong meaning when I first read the question but now that I have seen your answer I think your answer is in the right direction.